# Testing out Facebook comments with free hosting

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to learn how to insert facebook comments onto a website and the cache the comments made, using PHP.

I'm using free hosting for this, but it seems that Facebook apps won't let me register a free hosting address as my website. Is this so? If, so do you have any ideas as to how to practice facebook coding without buying a domain name? How can I create a testing environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS are you on? Edit your hosts file and add a custom dns name and you can do whatever you want.

Comment: But I need to give facebook a real website address. I'm using a windows 7 pc with xampp.

Comment: It should still work. I have been able to test facebook api locally only using LOCALHOST. Facebook only needs this information so it can do its crazy IFRAME hack.

Comment: Wow, it works. I have no idea how this link can actually see my comments: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://127.0.0.1/ptest.php

Answer (score 0):

Setup your own web server locally and use service such as http://www.afraid.org to get a free domain that can point to your own server.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the free host, you will need to install some certificates on your site. i had a similar problem, i solved it using the instructions given at this site ::

http://vadimg.com/2010/05/05/facebook-php-library-graph-social-plugins-search-posting-and-more/

its easy to follow.

Hope that helps.